# Dpad Focus on a particular view

Tags: android, d-pad

I'm having a splash screen and in that screen, I have few views like videoView, imageView, and button.
I want to get focused on my button at the start of the activity so that if I press ok from the remote of my Tv it should go to next activity
I have tried many things so far like focusable as true 
android:focusedByDefault="true"
but I'm unable to get the focus on the button